# Can't setup path alias typescript React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I trying to setup my path alias in React Native. I added needed paths into tsconfig and babel.config:

tsconfig:

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

and babel.config:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
          root: '.',
          alias: {
            '@app': './src',
            '@assets': './assets',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

But it trying to resolve my paths such way: `Unable to resolve "./src/*/hooks/useAppFonts" from "App.tsx"`.

What have I done wrong?